# Foreach loop inside jQuery Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm calling a php script by means of a jQuery Ajax call using the following syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slider').load('/php/test.php');
});
```

I'd like the php to output a series of images, like this:

```
<?php

    $sliderImages = glob('content/slider/projects/_img/*.jpg');

    foreach ($sliderImages as $currentSliderImages) { ?>

        <img class="slide mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="<?php echo $currentSliderImages; ?>">

    <?php };

?>
```

However, no image appears. If I replace the PHP file content with plain text, it does appear inside the div - i.e. the call is working.

Comment: What happens if you do `print_r($sliderImages)` before the loop?

Comment: Can only guess this path `'content/slider/projects/_img/*.jpg'` isnt relative to the php/test.php.

Comment: Thank you GrumpyCrouton and IncredibleHat. It was the issue of the content path not being relative to test.php. Please place the answer and I'll make it as correct.